# [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (PreLoginHandshake()).]General network error - connecting to SQL database in VB script

Tags: sql, database, vbscript, ado

I have a VB script which connects to a local SQL database to retrieve a value. The exact same script runs on about 100 servers, but a few of the servers produce this error:

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (PreLoginHandshake()).]General network error. Check your network documentation

Here is the code that runs:

```
Function GetPrimaryServerID
On Error Resume Next
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
sqlquery = "SELECT ServerID FROM tblSettings"
objRecordSet.Open sqlquery,objConnection
objRecordSet.MoveFirst
GetPrimaryServerID = objRecordSet("ServerID")
objRecordSet.Close
objConnection.Close 
End Function
```

The error occurs on the 5th line when trying to open the connection string. I'm confused as to why this script is working on nearly all servers and failing on only a handful. The database that they connect to is identical on every server in terms of structure, its only the data that changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by doing the following:
Opened SQL Server Configuration Manager and went to Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP. In the 'IP Addresses' tab, I noticed that IP2 which has address of 127.0.0.1 was active but not enabled. Changed to enabled and restarted SQL services. My VB script now successfully opens the connection to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a database error, but a client tools or config error

The failing servers will probably:

- have a different level of either SQL Server install /includes service pack)
- are configured for Windows Authentication only
- have an older MDAC (linked to SQL Service pack, OS Service pack etc)

Edit:

SQL Server SSL Encryption, [server side, is described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(SQL.90).aspx). And in [KB 316898](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898) too

- "Server side" requires only a server certificate and all connections are encrypted
- "client side" requires client certs and is optional, and only for that client

Certain client libraries (notably MS JDBC) do not support this.

If I've guessed right, you'll have either client or server SSL encryption set based on the server (your script is acting as a client)

- [a blog entry too](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/04/476705.aspx)

Comment: All servers have Windows 2003 R2 x64 SP2. 
All servers are using SQL Server 9.0.3042 64 bit. 
This includes the succeeding and failing servers. I have double checked the failing servers just to make sure. I'm not sure how to check MDAC version. 

I've just noticed that on the failing servers, when opening SQL Server Management Studio, I can't connect to 127.0.0.1, I have to connect to the server name. However on every other server I can connect to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This is the error when trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 on the failing servers through Management Studio: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.  When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

Comment: @VBScripter: can you ping 127.0.0.1? are these server configured for encrpytion?

Comment: yes i can ping 127.0.0.1, and the windows firewall is disabled. Can you please be more specific about your encryption question?

Answer (score 0):

It could fail if the database is not configured to listen to TCP/IP traffic.  The error "Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe." points in that direction.

You can test that with:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 1433
```

To configure where the server listens, use `SQL Server Network Utility" for SQL Server 2000, or "SQL Server Surface Area Configuration" for SQL Server 2005 and up.

Comment: ok I've done the telnet test and it failed, could not connect on port 1433. The servers are using SQL Server 2005, I've opened SQL Server Surface Area Configuration but can you please advise where I go to configure where the server listens?

Comment: @VBScripter: click on `Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections`, then `MSSQLSERVER` -> `Database Engine` -> `Remote Connections`, and make sure one of the options with TCP/IP is selected

Comment: 'local and remote connections' and 'Using both TCP/IP and named pipes' are selected, yet I still can't connect to 127.0.0.1 through management studio or telnet to 127.0.0.1 on port 1433.

Comment: @VBScripter: Check the logs for a line that looks like "SQL server listening on <ip>: <port>" (should be near startup) and verify that it's listening on port 1433?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem. I opened SQL Server Configuration Manager and went to Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP. In the 'IP Addresses' tab, I noticed that IP2 which has address of 127.0.0.1 was active but not enabled. It appears to be both active and enabled on the servers that are working. However, this change requires restart of SQL services, so I'll have to wait until after hours to test.

Answer (score 0):

It may also be mismatching calls to `WSAStartup` and `WSACleanup`. If you call `WSACleanup` too often then sockets stop working. And the SQL client will also break - which is usually the case for remote DB servers (as opposed to local instances accessed through named pipes etc.).

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to disable the WPF and this should solve the problem (Control Panel -> Windows Firewall).
2. If not, then you can also stop the service for firewall (from Services.msc --> Windows personal firewall)

Comment: It would help your answer a lot to explain why you think Windows Firewall might be at fault here.